# How to convert an Array of Point to a Rectangle

Tags: c#

I have an `Array` of `Point` and I want to make it a `Rectangle`.
There are 4 points. I draw these points as a `Polygon` and the output is a `Rectangle`.
How can I draw these four points as a `Rectangle`?
Meaning, I want to get the width and height of these points.

These are my four points:

```
 p1 :48.5, 196.5
 p2 :997.5, 196.5
 p2 :997.5, 692.5
 p2 :48.5, 692.5
```

So I want something like this:

```
RectangleF rec = new RectangleF(x, y, width, hight);
```

My `x` and `y` is `p1.x` , `p1.y`
How can I get the width and height from these points?

```
RectangleF rec = new RectangleF(p1.x, p1.y, width, hight);
```

Comment: I got out of breath reading your question, and had to inhale before I got to the end. Could you please add some punctuation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that:

```
Point p1 = new Point(48.5, 196.5);
Point p2 = new Point(997.5, 196.5);
Point p3 = new Point(997.5, 692.5);
Point p4 = new Point(48.5, 692.5);
```

You can create Rectangle as follow:

```
RectangleF rec = new RectangleF(p1.X, p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X, p3.Y - p1.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using [GraphicsPath()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
{
    PointF[] points = new PointF[] {
    new PointF(48.5f, 196.5f),
    new PointF(997.5f, 196.5f),
    new PointF(997.5f, 692.5f),
    new PointF(48.5f, 692.5f),
    };

    path.StartFigure();
    path.AddPolygon(points);
    path.CloseFigure();
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), path);
};
```